# Convert to Generic

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this function:

```
const getFilter = () => ({
  value1: null,
  value2: null

} as IFilter)

export interface IFilter {
  value1: object,
  value2: string
}
```

How do I convert this method in Generic, I want the interface to be `T` and properties getFilter to be extensible

Comment: Having seen your previous question, this doesn't really make much sense. Please give a more accurate overview of the problem because I'm not sure a generic is really warranted here. In your last question you mentioned having multiple interfaces. What is the problem with returning a common one from `getFilter`? No generics need be involved. Besides, all `fn = <T>() => ({} as T)` does is move the cast into a function call but `f<Something>()` is still the same as a non-generic `f() as Something`

Comment: @VLAZ I have interface filter and 3 interfaces extended this filter interface.
Each of the 3 interface has it own unique set of properties in addition to the IFilter properties

Comment: Should `getFilter` produce those properties or just produce the base filter?

Comment: @VLAZ getFilter should produce the basics properties and properties and properties separately for each extended interface

Comment: Then that's not what a generic does. Using type assertions (the `as`) *doesn't* change the shape of the object, it just makes the compiler consider it *as if* it's actually different. So, calling `fn<Something>()` and `fn<Something2>()` will have the exact same results, even if `Something` and `Something2` are different. Generics, and the type system in general, only exist at compile time ***not*** at runtime. At runtime both these calls would be `fn()` and that's it. You need a different solution like a factory to produce different objects.

Comment: @VLAZ - thank you. add that to the answer

Comment: @AndrewStark is `getFilter` in your question supposed to do some work to calculate the returned properties based on some arguments or is the intension to always return `value1` and `value2` as `null`?